# CSS border image is wider than the div

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

I am adding an image border in bottom of my div like this :

HTML:

```
<div class="view">
    <div class="shadow_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.view {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    width: 160px;
    height: 190px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    border-image-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.shadow_overlay {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/MrVzqyp.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:160px;
    height:190px;
}
```

This worked but in action `border-image` is wider than my `div`.

Problem pic:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

DEMO [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhggx0r/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like browsers assign a default width to borders when `border-image` is used (but the borders on the other sides are invisible because the `border-image-width` is `0px`). To avoid the borders from looking like they are overflowing the `div`, manually set the border widths on all other sides to 0px.

```
border-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
```

The behavior is seen in Chrome (upto v48.0.2535.0 dev-m), IE (Edge), Opera and Safari. The border image doesn't extend beyond the `div` in latest Firefox (v41.0.1) IE (v11),

```css
.view {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  width: 160px;
  height: 190px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.shadow_overlay {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/MrVzqyp.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="shadow_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

---

In the below snippet you can see how it looks as though all other sides have a 3px border. There is no clear explanation either in the Web or in the specs about whose behavior is correct (Chrome, Edge or FF, IE11).

```css
.view {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  width: 160px;
  height: 190px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
.view#two{
  border-width: 4px 3px 3px 3px;
}
.shadow_overlay {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/MrVzqyp.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="shadow_overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="view" id="two">
  <div class="shadow_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

---

The W3C Specs also say the following about border-image properties but in FF and IE11 the `border-image` is not shown when only `border-width` is provided and `border-image-width` is avoided.

> The border-image properties do not affect layout: layout of the box, its content, and surrounding content is based on the ‘border-width’ and ‘border-style’ properties only.

So, it seems like the behavior of `border-image` is still not standardized. I am leaning towards what is observed in Chrome, Edge because Microsoft, for some reason, seems to have changed the behavior from IE11 and so there must be a good reason for it.